# Tapping on a notification from lock screen opens app notification settings instead of the app

Tags: notifications

Sometimes (not always), tapping on a notification from the lock screen opens the App notification settings instead of the app.

For example, a K9 notification takes me to this screen:
[image]

This happens totally randomly and I don't understand what's causing it.

Anybody else noticed this?

Galaxy S6 / Marshmallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the press and hold delay from the accessibility settings fixed the problem.